# class cast exception in google app engine code

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to query the data store and cast it to a user defined object type. But, i am getting an class cast error. Please look into the code

```
   import com.gwt.samples.shared.List;

   public ArrayList<String> viewLists(String user_id) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    ArrayList<String> res;
    String[] ret;
            Query q=pm.newQuery(List.class);
            q.setFilter("owner_id == useridparam");
            q.declareParameters("String useridparam");

            try
            {
               res=(ArrayList<List>)q.execute(user_id); //error occurs here i guess
            }
            finally
            {
               q.closeAll();
            }
            return res;
         }
```

The problem occurs because query.execute returns an Object and it cannot be casted to the type ArrayList . But, i am following this example from [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html)

Please help

Comment: did you try Query q=pm.newQuery(ArrayList.class); ?

Comment: @deporter : List.class -> refers to my built in class List, not java.util.List

Comment: so how can you expect that it will be casted to ArrayList<List>?

Comment: Using `List` as a name for your class is a **bad** idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest:

1.Delete the line

```
import com.gwt.samples.shared.List;
```

2.Instead of

```
Query q=pm.newQuery(List.class);
```

and

```
res=(ArrayList<List>)q.execute(user_id); //error occurs here i guess
```

use

```
Query q=pm.newQuery(com.gwt.samples.shared.List.class);
```

and

```
res=(ArrayList<java.util.List>)q.execute(user_id);
```

When you say "error occurs here i guess", I presume that you can find out definitely by examining the relevant exception stack trace or log entry.

Also, I have just seen that your data member `res` is of data type `ArrayList<String>`, whereas your query will return (incorporating my code changes above) `java.util.List<com.gwt.samples.shared.List>`.

You will need to change the data type of either your query or `res` to get things to work.

I have a standard method for querying. The query return is stored in a `java.util.List`. I then do

```
java.util.List liResult = [My query];
ArrayList alResult = new ArrayList(liResult);
```

Ouside of my method, I cast my `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<[Query data type]>`.

Any help?

Comment: +1. Assuming that the query returns an `ArrayList` is just plain wrong, you must use the interface (`java.util.List` in this case).